# Normality of minimal rational component

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth Fano manifold with the non-nef tangent bundle. Let $K$ be a minimal rational component in $\text{Mor}(\mathbb{P}^1, X)$ with respect to the anti-canonical bundle. In other words, the degree of $f^*TX$ is minimal for every $f \in K$. It is known that a general element in $K$ is smooth.

Question:(1) Is $K$ normal?

(2) If $K$ is not normal, then what can we say about the co-dimension of singular locus of $K$? Is there any effective lower bound? ( of course co-dimension is at least 2 as a general member is smooth).

Comment: What about the case of quartic Fermat threefolds?  In positive characteristic it is even worse, cf. Beauville's article in the Grothendieck Festschrift.

Comment: I am interested in the field of complex numbers. However, I guess for Fermat's hypersurface every element is smooth.  So co-dimension is at least $n$ where $n$ is the dimension. I guess over complex numbers it is always at least of co-dimension 2.

Comment: @JasonStarr  In which volume, the article by Beauville's article appeared ?

Comment: I do not understand your comments.  The variety parameterizing lines on a quartic Fermat threefold is not normal.

Comment: In example (3) of section  2.4 of https://www.math.ens.psl.eu/~debarre/NotesGAEL.pdf, it has been mentioned that $\text{Mor}_1(\mathbb{P}^1, X)$ is smooth.

Comment: Probably smoothness does not imply normality in positive characteristics.

Comment: If I understood correctly then $K$, in general, need not be normal. However, the singular locus at least in characteristic zero has a co-dimension of at least 2.

Comment: Are you asking about the parameter space of lines containing a (fixed) general point of the Fano manifold?  That is smooth.  However, that is not what you asked about in your post.  The parameter space of all lines on a quartic Fermat threefold is not normal.

Comment: Yes. I got that.  A minimal rational curve passing through a general point is smooth. But a minimal rational curve not passing through a general point need not be smooth. My second question was about the co-dimension of such curves.

Comment: I recommend that you correct the statement of your question in the original post.